# Тире или двоеточие в приведенных предложениях?

Tags: пунктуация, тире-или-двоеточие

1. Что это за монстр такой: минотавр?
2. Минотавр - что это за монстр такой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. (1) ***Что это за монстр такой: минотавр?*** (2) ***Что это за монстр такой – минотавр?***

У Розенталя в таких предложениях ставится двоеточие или тире  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189#pp189  Пункт 6.  Параллельное употребление двоеточия и тире при обособлении пояснительных и уточняющих членов предложения

Эти знаки могут **заменять друг друга**, так как интонация присоединительного тире и двоеточия похожа – это понижение тона перед паузой.  Только в случае двоеточия делается более **длительная пауза,** предупреждающая о последующем раскрытии  темы. Поэтому автор делает выбор на свой вкус (по величине паузы).

2. (1) ***Минотавр:  что это за монстр такой***

Если это заглавие, то можно поставить двоеточие, но без вопросительного знака.

(2)  **Минотавр – что это за монстр такой?**  Если это первая фраза в статье про критское чудовище, то ставится тире. Это конструкция  **с именительным темы.**

В начале  предложения называется предмет как обозначение темы, затем ставится тире, а далее  следует основное предложение, в котором   имеется личное или указательное местоимение **в качестве слова-отсылки**. http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=63